# Implications of using a 2C-#18 twisted shield pair nec type cmr cable for RS-485

Tags: communication, rs485

The cable will be passing modbus and another equal cable will be used for loadshare. The total cable distance will be about 100ft. Its catalog number [E2032S](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/8638376463924f08c76638a6e4679c16.pdf).

I notice other threads related to CAT5, but am unsure if I'll be opening myself up to a lot of issues during commissioning if I don't get the correct cable with 120 Ω characteristic impedance.

Comment: What are the specifications of the cable you are considering?

Comment: Its catalog number E2032S.
https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/8638376463924f08c76638a6e4679c16.pdf
Thank you for the help.

Comment: The product you selected probably has a characteristic impedance of around 60 ohms due to the thin PVC insulation.There will be reflections and it could cause bit errors.

Comment: Thank you. No way to correct this by using 60ohm resistors rather than 120ohm at the ends?